# One Form transition effect

Tags: codenameone

I have one Form. I would like the form to appear like it is transitioning to other form when its content is being updated.

I have only one form whose content get updated and would like to have a transition effect as if I am moving to another form. Thanks.

```
    Label instruction = new Label();
    ImageViewer v = new ImageViewer();

    instruction.setText(levels.nextS());
    v.setImage(levels.nextI());



    Button b = new Button("Submit");



    b.addActionListener(x -> {

        instruction.setText(levels.nextS());
        v.setImage(levels.nextI());

        current.animateHierarchy(300);
        current.show();

    });

    current.add(FlowLayout.encloseCenter(score));
    current.add(FlowLayout.encloseCenter(instruction));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could call `animateHeirachy` or `animateLayout` after adding the content:

```
myForm.add(cmp);
myForm.animateHierarchy(300);
```

replace `myForm` with the container you are adding the content to.

Comment: Thanks, I will surely try it today

Comment: It worked partially. See a bit of animation on the label but the radio buttons and ImageView do not get animated ....

Comment: Post some code snippets here for us to understand what you've tried already.

Comment: b is a button. Instruction is a label and v is ImageViewer and here is the code.                  b.addActionListener(x -> {
   instruction.setText(levels.nextS());
   v.setImage(levels.nextI());
   current.animateHierarchy(300);
   })

Comment: If I remove all from the Form and all them all again I think it works but it is a waste of CPU cycles

Comment: Edit your question to add the snippet

Comment: You are calling `show()` after the animation. `show()` method doesn't seem to be valid here.

Comment: With show() and without it you get similar behaviour.  First I did not have it then I tried with it.

Comment: I don't see where `current` was modified to justify an `animateHierarch` call? Diamond is correct that `show()` shouldn't be used for a showing form